# Scrumptuous Facebook Sample Doesn't Work on Real iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I downloaded facebook sdk. I run scurmptuous sample there, which is the main sample.

If I run at simulator, the sdk doesn't post anything.

If I run it at my own iPhone I keep getting this

First it goes to

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                     }];    
}
```

Then it quickly goes to the completion handler. The state of state is
FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed

IMMEDIATELY

It doesn't seem to try to connect to facebook or doing anything.

In my own program I used the exact same code and can login just fine.

I can run scrumptuous on simulator just fine.

The error code is this:

```
(lldb) po error
$0 = 0x1e891580 Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1dd87870 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason}
```

Before at least I can still see which facebook URL is being called and see where things went' wrong. Now nothing. It just (doesn't) works.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in settings, facebook is turned of for scrumptuous Turning that to on would fix the issue.

It's not clear, who turn that off. Is off the default? Who knows.

Deleting scrumptuous from the iPhone doesn't make it default to turn on.

This is just right. Most users would not be able to figure out that they got to go to settings and turned on things.